# Genexus 17 con Open JDK

Tags: genexus

Alguien ya tuvo experiencias en compilar con Genexus 17 y Open Jdk 17, yo estoy haciendo unas pruebas y me sale un error al tratar de arrancar la webapp

```
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type javax.jws.WebService not present
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.generateException(TypeNotPresentExceptionProxy.java:47)
    at java.base/sun.reflect.annotation.AnnotationInvocationHandler.invoke(AnnotationInvocationHandler.java:89)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy2.value(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1869)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1297)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5082)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si, estoy trabajando con GeneXus 17, tanto u4 como u5, compilando con Oracle y OpenJDK y sin dramas hasta el momento. Tambien tengo webapps publicadas con ambas jvms funcionando. El error te da al compilar con Genexus o al tratar de levantar la webapp. Todo indica que esta faltando la libreria javax.jws-3.1.2.2.jar.

Comment: Efectivamente esa librería no esta en el web-inf/lib, es raro que no lo haya copiado el gx